# how to parse custom html element using ng-bind-html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I need to parse a string using ng-bind-html. This string contains some custom html tags in it. Which while parsing using ng-bind-html gives me an error for $sanitize:badparse.

Please see the fiddle for error: http://jsfiddle.net/8zS4h/2/

While reading questions in stackoverflow and in google I found that there could be a solution if I use `$sce.trustAsHtml()`.

This solves my error issue but couldn't parse my custom html element.
You can see this updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8zS4h/3/

I am scratching hard my head to find a solution.

**EDIT :**
Just to add more info, I am getting this string from a rss feed, so sometimes it can have `"<http>"` or `"<http"` tags also. Which is where it is failing.
So if the string is like `<http://www.<em>whitehouse</em>.gov/omb/circulars/a076/` should gives output like `http://www.<em>whitehouse</em>.gov/omb/circulars/a076/`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to get working tags like anchor, underline and bold without problem, look:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg54W/)

```
angular.module('ngBindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ngBindHtmlCtrl', ['$scope', function ngBindHtmlCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML =
        '<a href=\"http://google.com\">link</a> contests <u>of OMB</u> <b>Circular</b> A-76';
  }])
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        }; 
}]);
```

seems like it's parsed correctly

Comment: This is fine but what to do if I have tags like "<http>" or "<http"

Comment: it works fine, you just need to use correct syntax. eg. <http></http> is fine, but this '<http' needs a closing '>' and ending element

Comment: That's a problem, We are getting this string from rss feed and before inserting it into database, we are truncating the string with first 50 characters. Now it can have a closing '<' or can not. Thanks for your comment.